# Need to populate table based on data in a csv file

Tags: sql, database, for-loop, rodbc

I have a database table called "COL" that contains over 836,000 items purchased online by individuals.  There is a distinct set of 330 items that I read in as a .csv file called "desc".  Rather than deal with all 836,000 individual items, I would like to group them from 1 to 330.  For this I've created a column in the table called "groups".

What I would like to do is read in an item from desc and update the table using an update query, but I'm a bit lost on how to set it up.  I've provided some code, but I'm not sure how to run an update query in a for loop.

```
library(RODBC)
db <- "C:/Projects/stuff.accdb"
desc<-read.csv("C:/Projects/description.csv",header=TRUE)
col <- odbcConnectAccess2007(db)
for (i in 330)
{
  sqlquery(col,paste("update COL set groups=1 where description='SLIP-ONS, LT, GREEN'"))
}
close(col)
```

Comment: I know this isn't what is being asked, but you may take a look at the issue from a different angle and see if there is a way that you can handle this via sql or another tool. If you are using MSSQL, you could import the csv file into its own table and then use a query to do the work that you need done (possibly taking advantage of the sql merge statement).

Comment: A very good suggestion. Thank you.